# Error in WSO2 claims configuration with LDAP(Active directory)

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

We have done WSO2 IS configurations with multiple LDAPs with multiple clients successfully before. This time with a new client we are getting an error as show in image. "Error occured while getting all user claims for ... in carbon.super.

[image]

The case is we have created a service and mapped custom claims to map to LDAP. The issue is with a field mapped with http://wso2.org/claims/role attribute . If we remove this attribute from the custom claims the error goes away.

But we are using roles in business logic(Internal roles created in WSO2) which we get as null in case we remove this attribute.

We want to know the solution. Is there some change required at LDAP side ? Or how we can achieve the roles without mapping as a claim with LDAP?